# Login system: sql vs secondairy php file

Tags: php, sql, authentication, passwords

I don't really like using sql databases. I want to make a login system. Is there any security problem with having a passwords.php file with the passwords in  it rather than having them in a database? I figure since php is server side, nobody should be able to access php code in passwords.php but what do I know?

Comment: Come on! On hold? It's true or false. Is saving passwords in a file on the server as secure as in a database or isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, no problem at all. In fact this is how `.htpasswd` stores its passwords.

But it makes adding, removing or editing them much, much harder than it needs to be.

Databases are quick, simple, and easy to use. You should probably use one.

So to sum up, if you have a small, unchanging set of users (for instance, you're making something for yourself and your friends only), then a file-based password storage is probably okay (assuming proper encryption and stuff). Otherwise, use a DB.